# Toggle Boolean in Jackson JsonNode

Tags: java, jackson, boolean

Is there a most efficient way of an empty field check?
I don't like "!".

```
private boolean isEmpty(JsonNode node, String textField) {
    return !(node.hasNonNull(textField) && node.get(textField).isTextual());
}
```

Comment: Well, you could use redundancy: `return (node.hasNonNull(textField) && node.get(textField).isTextual()) == false;` or `return (node.hasNonNull(textField) && node.get(textField).isTextual()) ? false : true ;`.  But, that might be regarded as poor style, which could annoy  others who have to work with your code in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you actually want to check? Your method checks it is not empty but it is named `isEmpty`. It is really confusing. Let's consider below method:

```java
private static boolean isEmpty(JsonNode parent, String fieldName) {
    final JsonNode field = parent.get(fieldName);
    return Objects.nonNull(field) && field.isTextual() && StringUtils.isEmpty(field.asText());
}
```

It retrieves field based on the name from the parent object only once. Using reference we can check it is not null, it is textual and what actually value is.

Take a look on the below code:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Objects;

public class NodeIsEmptyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .build();


        JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, JsonNode.class);

        System.out.println("Original method:");
        node.fieldNames()
                .forEachRemaining(fieldName ->
                        System.out.println(fieldName + "( " + node.get(fieldName) + ") is empty = " + originalIsEmpty(node, fieldName)));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("New method:");
        node.fieldNames()
                .forEachRemaining(fieldName ->
                        System.out.println(fieldName + "( " + node.get(fieldName) + ") is empty = " + isEmpty(node, fieldName)));
    }

    private static boolean isEmpty(JsonNode parent, String fieldName) {
        final JsonNode field = parent.get(fieldName);
        return Objects.nonNull(field) && field.isTextual() && StringUtils.isEmpty(field.asText());
    }

    private static boolean originalIsEmpty(JsonNode node, String textField) {
        return !(node.hasNonNull(textField) && node.get(textField).isTextual());
    }
}
```

For this `JSON` payload:

```json
{
  "null": null,
  "empty": "",
  "nonEmpty": "text",
  "array": [],
  "object": {},
  "number": 123,
  "boolean": true
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Original method:
null( null) is empty = true
empty( "") is empty = false
nonEmpty( "text") is empty = false
array( []) is empty = true
object( {}) is empty = true
number( 123) is empty = true
boolean( true) is empty = true

New method:
null( null) is empty = false
empty( "") is empty = true
nonEmpty( "text") is empty = false
array( []) is empty = false
object( {}) is empty = false
number( 123) is empty = false
boolean( true) is empty = false
```